# Where is Jerome supposed to be from?

Tags: nymphomaniac

In Lars Von Trier's *Nymphomaniac*, Shia Lebouf plays a character called Jerome, who has an unidentifiable accent.

I don't know if he is supposed to be English, but as an Englishman myself I can confirm it definately isn't an English accent. It's not even a dialect, it sounds like a South-African Australian Hybrid.

Is this intentional? is there any evidence anywhere to confirm or deny that the character is supposed to be anything other than English?

---

At my cinema we had 12 people walk out of the film last night, 9 of them citing his performance as a point of ridicule meaning they could no longer take the film seriously. Ouch.

Answer (score 5):

I had a quick browse on the official website and looked at a few interviews with the cast members, but no one ever actually says where he is from.

I am pretty convinced however that he is supposed to be English (especially given the amount of websites/videos mocking him for his attempt at an English accent) and so I think it's just another example of an actor getting an accent horribly, horribly wrong (see Russell Crowe in [Robin Hood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood_%282010_film%29)).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. At least Russel Crowe was attempting a Northern Vernacular, and can be forgiven for at least *trying* to incorporate anglican colloquialisms, even if it didn't pull off. I still think he might be supposedly non-English: I can't imagine von Trier being satisfied with how jarring his accent is.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphomaniac_(film)) lists Shia as `Jerôme Morris`, taking into account the spelling suggests the person to be originary from France.

[Jérôme(French), Jerome (English)](http://familyeducation.com/baby-names/name-meaning/jerome)

Also [this entry](https://www.indiewire.com/2013/12/the-nymphomaniac-cheat-sheet-everything-you-need-to-know-about-lars-von-triers-epic-study-of-sexual-obsession-2-31909/) may suggest the origin of Jerome:

> It’s not exactly a spoiler to note that the main male part in
> “Nymphomaniac,” the person who poses the threat of falling in love
> with Joe or being loved by her goes by the very French name of Jerôme
> — and that the child Joe and Jerôme will have together, the proof of
> their love, is called Marcel, also the first name of a certain French
> novelist.

Based on this, I would suggest Shia's accent to be french.